# Forcing GetCustomAttributes to throw AmbiguousMatchException

Tags: c#, .net, class, attributes

In the example below, I would expect a call to `GetCustomAttributes` to throw an `AmbiguousMatchException` but it does not.

```
[CompatibleCaste(typeof(KannadaVaishya))]
[CompatibleCaste(typeof(VaishyaVani))]
public class Vaishya : Caste { /* is not matter */ }
```

Per [MSDN ICustomAttributeProvider.GetCustomAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezk6ae46%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#Y119), it should throw a `AmbiguousMatchException` -- how can I demonstrate this fact?

Comment: The code that calls `GetCustomAttributes` is relevant; please post it.

Comment: is not option - the array in attribute constructor is not COMPLIANT of the cls

Comment: @Austin Salonen 1 min ago - is not relevant, i not get exception, but am needful of HOW GET exception, is possible?

Comment: @PRASHANTP:  Please confirm my edits that I did not change the intent of the question.

Comment: @AustinSalonen is near, do not want force, but have understand of how get is all

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are asking...

When you are defining you custom attribute class, you need to AllowMultiple.

`[AttributeUsage(AllowMultiple=true)]`

Then you can use the same attribute multiples on the same method or class.

Comment: i have this, i not get compiler error, am wonder, how get ambiguousmatchexception??

Comment: @PRASHANTP You want to know how to get that exception?

Comment: similar, you see i have yet 2 of same attribute of no exception - is documentation LIE?